# Java Thread: Run method cannot throw checked exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

In Java thread, the 'run' method cannot throw a 'checked exception'. I came across this in the Core Java (vol 1)  book. Can someone please explain the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Where would the exception go? The thread that spawned the new thread has since moved on. So, how would the new thread "send" the exception to the origination thread that had fired and forgotten said thread?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Can someone please explain the reasoning behind it?

Yes, because any exception you throw in `run` method will be carefully ignored by JVM. Thus, throwing it there is probably a mistake (unless you have specific exception handler for the thread, see [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) about that). No reason to incite potentially erroneous behaviour.

Or, with an example.

```
 class MyThread extends Thread {
     public void run() {
         throw new RuntimeException();
     }
 }

...

new MyThread().start();
// here thread dies silently with no visible effects at all
```

**edit**

> Why can't the parent thread 'catch' the exception from the spawned 'child' thread?

**@chaotic3quilibrium** has already noted in his comment why not: because parent thread has likely moved on already.

```
new MyThread().start(); // launch thread and forget

// 1000 lines of code further...
i = i + 1; // would you like exception from child thread to be propagated here?
```

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind the JVM carefully ignoring the exceptions in `run`?

Comment: @Martinho What else can it do? Suicide option sounds even worse: you wouldn't want the whole application to crash because of one thread.

Comment: Silenty ignoring is perhaps misleading. The exception will be handled by the thread's UncaughtExceptionHandler, the default implementation of which will dump the stacktrace to System.err before killing the thread. As for why: How would the VM know what to do instead?

Comment: @Nikita: Well, I might. How dare the JVM decide which threads are essential and which are not? Quoting Eric Lippert on the CLR "you'd start up a bunch of worker threads, they'd all throw exceptions, and you'd end up with a running application with no worker threads left, doing no work, and not telling the user about it. It is better to force the author of the code to handle the situation where a worker thread goes down due to an exception; doing it the old way effectively hides bugs and makes it easy to write fragile applications."

Comment: Why can't the parent thread 'catch' the exception from the spawned 'child' thread? After all the JVM knows which parent thread is really interested about the exception?

Comment: @Martinho This is exactly why you should decide yourself which threads are important and give them proper exception handling :) JVM can't decide that for you.  As for terminating the whole VM... I don't know, that sounds a bit like overreacting to me.

Comment: @user: the "parent" thread may be long gone by that time. You have only two choices: ignore it, or bring the whole thing down.

Comment: @Nikita: But as meriton pointed out, the thread does not die silently with *no visible effects at all*. It runs the UncaughtExceptionHandler. That sounds reasonable to me. I personally prefer "bring the thing down" as approach when there's no handler, but having a handler is good enough.

Comment: @Martinho Well, I kinda mentioned exception handlers in my post.

Comment: @NikitaRybak I really can't see how this example could work. If `MyThread` extends Thread then you have to override run() `Subclasses of <code>Thread</code> should override this method.` and the signature of run doesn't have a throws Exception therefore  any error that you might throw from your `run` implementation will be truncated. Am I wrong? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 13):

What would catch the exception and handle it? Let's assume that the run method could throw a checked exception. Then you could write code like this:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(aRunnable);
try{
    myThread.start();
}
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
//do other stuff
```

BUT once you call `myThread.start`, the new thread is started in the background and the current thread continues and exits the try-catch and does other stuff. So if `myThread` did throw an exception later on, you can't catch it!

What you need to do is deal with the exception within the `run` method and then probably have a way of notifying another object that this thread failed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose thread A starts up thread B. Then thread B throws an exception. You might think it would be nice for thread A to catch it. But where? By the time thread B thows the exception, who knows what thread A is doing? To take a trivial example, suppose we have this code in thread A:

```
try
{
  threadB=new PurgeAbandonedCarts();
  threadB.start();
}
catch (NullPointerException panic)
{
  ... handle errors purging abandoned carts ...
}
try
{
  processNewOrders();
}
catch (NullPointerException panic)
{
  ... handle problems in new orders ...
}
finally
{
  ... clean up ...
}
```

So we start up thread B to purge abandoned carts. Once it gets starte, we move on to processing new orders. Then thread B throws a null pointer exception.  Should it be caught by the catch block associated with thread B, or the one associated with processing new orders?

If it goes to the new orders catch, it's likely that any code here has nothing to do with cleaning up problems with thread B. That can't be the right answer.

If you say the one associated with thread B, then that means that during the processing of new orders, control could suddenly be yanked out and sent back to try thread B catch block. But then what happenned to processing new orders? Do we just stop in the middle? Do we not even hit the finally block? And when we're done, do we then just keep executing and fall through to processing new orders again? Do we process orders twice? This can't be the right answer either.

Thus, there is nowhere to go if run throws an exception. The only logical thing to do is to have the run method catch any exceptions thrown itself, and handle them within the new thread.

Answer (score 0):

`throws` declarations are part of the methods signature. To allow checked exceptions for `Runnable#run`, one had to declare them on the `Runnable` interface and had to `try/catch` everytime we start a thread.

Then again, we usually don't call the `run` method, we just implement it. We `start()` a Thread and then, somehow, the `run` method is called.

But the most obvious reason: When we start threads, we usually don't want to wait until the `run` method terminates just to catch exceptions like this:

```
try {
   new Worker().start();  // now wait until run has finished
} catch (SomeThreadException oops) {
   // handle checked exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that exception is thrown back to the caller. Caller of run() method is not your code. It is the Thred itself. So even if run() throws exception the program cannot catch it.

You should put thread execution result to some class level variable and then read it from there. Or alternatively use new API: executors and interface Callable that declares method call() that returns future result  of the thread execution.

Answer (score 0):

The more obvious solution to the previous answers is that if you throw a checked exception, you are not correctly implementing run() as specified in the runnable interface.

It won't even compile:

```
run() in TestClass cannot implement run() in java.lang.Runnable; 
overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception
```