# No exception caught with Runnable

Tags: java, exception, runnable

I am fairly new to Java threads, Runnable, and the like.
As such, I'm wondering why the following code does not catch an exception?

```
Runnable r = () -> {
    try {
        job.print(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

if (job.printDialog()) {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    r.start();
}
```

Reading [Is there a way to make Runnable's run() throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584159/is-there-a-way-to-make-runnables-run-throw-an-exception) I gather that:

1. "*... if your run() method is really the target of a Thread, there's no point in throwing an exception because it is unobservable; throwing an exception has the same effect as not throwing an exception (none).*" ([@erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474/erickson))
2. I should check for exceptions inside the Runnable.run() method.

Why is that? Any "simple" explanations on this matter are highly appreciated!

Comment: Re, "I should check for exceptions inside run()... Why is that?" Why not? If you want to write a top-level handler for exceptions thrown within the thread, where would you prefer to put it? Why _not_ use the already exising `try...catch...` mechanism in the thread's top-level function?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out already, there's nothing thats captured outside `Runnable` running state. Language specifications keep on changing. What might have an explanation today may have something else tomorrow. You might find the answer at [Why cannot run() of Runnable throw checked Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410042/why-cannot-run-of-runnable-throw-checked-exceptions), specifically as to why `Callable` was added to capture the results from `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer this question from both, a logical and a programmatical point of view. 
Let's start with the logical one:

You can think of a thread as an "independent executor of code" which is totally independent from other executors of code, except shared memory. The `Runnable` you have to pass on thread initialization "wraps" the code the thread has to execute. As there's no "higher instance" which could catch an exception, throwing exceptions inside those `Runnable`s doesn't make a lot of sense.

Now the programmatical point of view. The following code snippet is similar to how the interface is defined inside the Java SE:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface Runnable {
    void run();
}
```

As the function `#run()` does NOT throw any checked exceptions, you're not allowed to throw checked exceptions inside `#run()`. Since `Runnable`s have been designed for use in thread initialization only, this makes perfect sense. `Callable`s, however, contain a `throws`-clause as they're mainly used in `Executor`s which indeed are able to handle exceptions.