# How does one throw an exception from a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I need to throw an exception. The only issue is that the exception is thrown from a thread started from within the method.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
public void connectToWebsite(String URL){
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
           openURLConnection(URL);//Throws Malformed URL and IO Exception
        }
   };
}
```

This is part of an API so I want to allow the users of the API to handle the exception how they so choose. However, I cannot get `connectToWebsite(url)` to throw the exception as the exception is thrown within run. I cannot get `run()` to throw the exception as then it would not be overriding the run method. Is there a way I can get the exception is thrown without building an entire new thread class? Or should I just settle on adding a catch with `printStackTrace`s?

I would ideally like a `connectToWebsite` to throw an exception and have the user handle it. However, is that even possible? If so, how? If I cannot or should not throw an Exception how should I notify the user something went wrong?

Comment: Which API you write to declare to throw exception, use it on methods

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491606/java-thread-run-method-cannot-throw-checked-exception

Comment: http://book.javanb.com/java-threads-3rd/jthreads3-CHP-13-SECT-5.html just found that. Take a look at it. Uncaught exceptions are handled via a method that can be rewritten. The thread in which the exception occured is passed as a parameter to this handler.

Comment: As @Thüzhen suggests, there is a default exception handler that "catches" exception that make it all the way to the root frame of a thread without being handled.  The app developer can (if not prohibited by JVM authority rules) change this handler to do the developer's bidding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get the exception is thrown without building an entire new thread class? Or should I just settle on adding a catch with printStackTraces?

There are a couple of things you can do.  The best is arguably to switch to use an `ExecutorService` and use a `Callable` instead of a runnable.  You can submit your `Callable` to the `ExecutorService` which returns a `Future`.  When you call `future.get()` it will throw an exception if your `call()` method threw an exception.  It actually throws `ExecutionException` and the cause of that exception will be the exception thrown by `call()`.

You can also use an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and set it on the `Thread`.  Then if you thread throws, the handler will be called with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`Runnable` cannot throw exception or return values.

One thing which could be done is to let the object which is created by `openURLConnection` to null. So the users will check

```
if (object == null) { /* something went wrong with url connection */ }
else {
/* all ok */
}
```

and knows if something went wrong or not.

It depends to how your API works.