# Why Run method of thread class does not allow to throw exception?

Tags: java

I am searching on net but did not get satisfactory answers that what made Sun engineers to 
disallow run method of Runnable interface for throwing an exception.

Comment: The `run` method is `Runnable`'s.

Comment: Which portion of your program would catch such an exception?

Comment: @thd Which it implements from `Runnable`.

Comment: @TheLostMind [nitpicky] It's still `Runnable`'s method because a `Thread` _is a_ `Runnable`. [/nitpicky]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to be __specific programming problems__ expressed _clearly_. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intention behind the concept of multi-threading is to allow parallel processing of two or more tasks for which the run method is used. If the `run` method throws a `CheckedException`, in that case the calling thread has to wait in the corresponding catch block to wait for the same which defies the sole purpose of multi-threading.

`For example`: Consider the following HYPOTHETICAL scenario
The `main thread` starts another thread say `Thread1` which supposedly say does throw some `CheckedException`. Now to catch that exception, the corresponding catch block has to be put somewhere. Lets say the main method itself has the same. Now to catch that exception (generate by the Thread1's run method), the main thread has to wait inside the catch block to let the execution of Thread1's run method complete which will not be acceptable as then there would be no use of multithreading here.

Moreover the Future and Callable tasks are based on the above hypothesis only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess that is something plausible.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question can be a question to ask yourself that if run method throws an exception then what would catch it?

From the [JCIP docs](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jcip-sample.pdf):

> Runnable is a fairly limiting abstraction; run can not return a value
>   or throw checked exception .

However you can use `Callable`, and submit it to an `ExecutorService` and waiting for result with `FutureTask.isDone()` returned by the `ExecutorService.submit()`

Something like this:

```
Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() {
        // whatever you want
        return null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To fill that gap since Jdk 1.5 onwords [`Callable<V>`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) is introduced which provides you create async task and that returns a result and may throw an exception.

Code snippet -

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
       ... 
    }

}
```

...

```
FutureTask<String> futureTask1 = new FutureTask<String>(new MyCallable());
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(futureTask1);
try{
    String result = futureTask1.get();
    ...
}catch(Exception ex){ // catch that exception
}
```

Comment: Callable was added when you can add individual tasks to an Executor where you can capture the result in a Future and any exception thrown.

Comment: Yes  and Executor having thread pool which execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The calling method does not call the `run()` directly to start a `Thread`. One needs to call `Thread.start()` which in turn calls a `run()` method. So there is no point in throwing an checked exception from the `run()` method.

Also, any exception you throw in run method will be carefully ignored by JVM. Thus, throwing it there is probably a mistake (unless you have specific exception handler for the thread)

Refer this for more explanation: [Java Thread: Run method cannot throw checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491606/java-thread-run-method-cannot-throw-checked-exception)

Comment: we can catch after the thread is started . By enclosing thread.start() in try catch.

Answer (score 0):

**Checked Exception vs Unchecked Exception.**

The first point is a wrong assumption that `run()` method cannot throw an exception. See  the below code compiles

```
public class Test  extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
    }

}
```

And now see the below code , which is won't compile.

```
public class Test  extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
    }

}
```

The point is the run() nethod cannot throws  a Checked Exception, If it can throw which Exception we would catch ??

Comment: If main() allows us to throw exception and JVM handles it then why not JVM handles run() exception.

Answer (score 0):

if any calling method(for example void m1()) throws exception called method (pp.m1()) has to either solve or rethrow the exception just follows////

```
        public class Practice14 {

         public void m1() throws Exception{


         System.out.println("hello");

          }

      public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Practice14 pp=new Practice14();

    try {

        pp.m1();//here solving the exception

    } catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

so because start() method in thread doesn't have capability to solve the exception run method won't allow you to throws exception