# Exception in child thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a new Thread from the main thread using the below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            new TestThread().start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Inside main");

    }
```

And throwing an exception. I am able to catch it in the main thread also.But according to [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491606/java-thread-run-method-cannot-throw-checked-exception)

this shouldn't be the case right?

EDIT:

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {

throw new RuntimeException();
}

 }
```

Exception Trace

```
Inside main
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at TestThread.run(TestThread.java:8)
```

Comment: What exception are we talking about?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What makes you think that you are catching it in the main thread?

Comment: The main thread can only catch exceptions that occur inside of the constructor or inside of `start` (for example not enough free memory to create another thread). You don't get to see exceptions from `run`.

Comment: Re, "...child thread..." The knowledge that thread B was created by thread A might mean something to _you_, but the JVM does not care.  There's several reasons why it does not make sense for an uncaught exception in a thread to be re-thrown in the "parent" thread, but in Java, one of those reasons is that the JVM won't even remember which thread is the "parent."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you refer to is "Java Thread: Run method cannot throw checked exception".

In Java, Thread's run method cannot throw checked exceptions because it would involve changing the signature of the `run()` method. However, in your example, you throw a `RuntimeException`, which isn't a checked exception. See [*Understanding checked vs unchecked exceptions in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/understanding-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java).

Note, however, that you are not actually catching the exception in the main thread: replace the `printStackStrace` statement with something like `...println("caught")` for this to be more obvious.

Comment: But that exception will still not propagate to the main thread somehow. All it will do is crash whatever thread is executing `run()`.

Comment: @SDJ, I updated the question with the stacktrace. I think what you mean is I wont get the entry of .start() method which is present in the main thread right?

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions thrown by a thread's `run()` method, are not caught by the main thread but handled by the JVM.
If you want to manage this situation, you should use the `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` method.

Something like this:

```
class MyHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
  {
    System.out.println("Caught exception " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

class MyThread extends Thread
{
  public MyThread()
  {
    setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyHandler());
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    throw new RuntimeException("ciao");
  }
}
```

Comment: But I am catching the exception in the main as per the code.

Comment: @ghostrider No you're not. Try changing the exception handler in your main thread. You'll see it doesn't get there. The output you see now comes directly from the JVM

Comment: @ghostrider, Re, "I am catching the exception in main..." You wrote an exception handler that _would_ catch an exception thrown by `start()` _IF_ `start()` threw an exception. But the exception that is thrown in the new thread will not cause `start()` to thrown an exception. In fact, it's possible that `start()` could return, and the main thread could print its message and _terminate_ before the new thread gets to throw its exception.